# How to load existing local dataset into Tensorflow and scale images [0,255] to [-1,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I have my own dataset that is split to Train and test directories. Like this:

```
LFW-A:
 |
 |
 |___ Train
        |
        |
        |___images...
 |
 |
 |___ Test
        |
        |
        |___images...
```

Currently, I am loading the MNIST dataset like this:

```
(trainX, trainy), (testX, testY) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

My own dataset is in the same directory. How can I load that instead of the builtin MNIST?

This is my function:

```
# load fashion mnist images
def load_real_samples():
    # load dataset
    (trainX, trainy), (testX, testY) = load_data()
    # expand to 3d, e.g. add channels
    X = expand_dims(trainX, axis=-1)
    # convert from ints to floats
    X = X.astype('float32')
    # scale from [0,255] to [-1,1]
    X = (X - 127.5) / 127.5
    return [X, trainy]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) and `preprocessing_function` for preprocessing and scale images from `[0,255] to [-1,1]` and use [`flow_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) for loading images from local path. Suppose the dataset in the local path is like the below.

[image]

**Reading from local path**

```
import tensorflow as tf

def preprc_func(img):
    img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
    # scale from [0,255] to [-1,1]
    img = (img - 0.5) * 2
    return img

datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprc_func
)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(100, 100),
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical')
test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/test',
        target_size=(100, 100),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

# Found 30 images belonging to 3 classes.
# Found 30 images belonging to 3 classes.
```

**Check one image:**

```
>>> next(iter(train_generator))[0][0].shape
(100, 100, 3)


>>> next(iter(train_generator))[0][0]
array([[[[ 0.082353  ,  0.082353  ,  0.082353  ],
         [ 0.62352943,  0.62352943,  0.62352943],
         [-0.05098039, -0.05098039, -0.05098039],
         ...,
         [-0.42745095, -0.42745095, -0.42745095],
         [-0.7411765 , -0.7411765 , -0.7411765 ],
         [-0.8980392 , -0.8980392 , -0.8980392 ]]]], dtype=float32)
```

**Show one image after loading from path:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(next(iter(train_generator))[0][0])
```

[image]

**Generate random images for this answer:**

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

for idx, loc in enumerate(['data/train', 'data/test']*10):
    for category in ['class_1', 'class_2', 'class_3']:
        imarray = np.random.rand(100,100) * 255
        im = Image.fromarray(imarray.astype('uint8'))
        im.save(f'{loc}/{category}/img_{idx}.png')
```